# Can i get a tidy solution to the below nested function

Tags: r

The function works fine on a df containing 1000 to 20,000 cases but anything more than that and it takes hours (5 hours plus) and right now i have a df that's 57635985 observation long

Suppose a df like this:

```
d<-structure(list(ReviewType= c("Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Review","Review","Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction","Correction", 
                                "Correction", "Deficiency", "Deficiency", "Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction"),
                  Submissiondate= c("2020-08-29 04:32:00","2020-08-28 04:31:00","2020-08-26 04:31:00","2020-08-25 04:31:00","2020-08-24 04:31:00","2020-08-23 04:31:00","2020-08-22 04:31:00","2020-08-21 04:31:00","2020-08-20 04:31:00","2020-08-19 04:31:00",
                                    "2020-09-27 04:31:00","2020-09-27 03:52:59","2020-09-28 17:30:00","2020-09-29 14:01:00",
                                    "2020-09-05 03:00:00","2020-09-05 03:51:00", "2020-09-03 23:59:49",
                                    "2020-09-02 00:03:54","2020-09-01 00:04:48","2020-10-01 04:31:00","2020-10-11 04:31:00","2020-10-21 04:31:00"),
                  CaseNo= c("124","123","125","121","121","125","123","123","123","123","123","123","123","125","123","123","123","124","123","127","127","127")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))


d<-d%>%arrange(CaseNo,Submissiondate)
```

The code below is trying to see for each case number, as long as the status stayed at correction at each week's end, it will be counted in the stats for all the subsequent weeks till the status changes to anything:

```
d <- d %>% mutate(Submissiondate = as.Date(Submissiondate), 
                  weekday = wday(Submissiondate), 
                  week.end = Submissiondate + 7 - weekday) 


#1 End state for each case and week
EndStates <- d %>% 
  group_by(CaseNo, week.end) %>% 
  summarize(WeekEndState = last(ReviewType)) %>% ungroup()

#2 Get unique values of Case/Week.end/ReviewType
chk <- d %>%
  select(CaseNo, week.end, ReviewType) %>%
  distinct()

#3 Add the EndStates and count if the week had a correction AND
#   the week ended as a Correction
chk <- left_join(chk, EndStates, by = c("CaseNo", "week.end"))

cor_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(unique(chk$CaseNo))+1, 
                               nrow=length(unique(chk$week.end))))
names(cor_df) <- c("week.end", unique(chk$CaseNo))
cor_df$week.end <- unique(chk$week.end)
for(i in 1:nrow(cor_df)){
      for(j in 2:ncol(cor_df)){
            this_CaseNo_idx = chk$CaseNo == strtoi(names(cor_df)[j])
            idx =  this_CaseNo_idx & 
                  chk$week.end == max(chk$week.end[chk$week.end <= cor_df$week.end[i] &
                                                         this_CaseNo_idx])
            if (sum(idx) < 1){
                  cor_df[i, j] = 0
            }
            else{
                  
                  cor_df[i, j] = max(ifelse(chk$WeekEndState[idx] == "Correction" & 
                                              chk$ReviewType[idx] == "Correction", 
                                            1, 0))
            }
            
      }
}
cor_df$asw <- rowSums(cor_df[,2:ncol(cor_df)])
cor_df <- cor_df[order(cor_df$week.end),]
data.frame(week.end=cor_df$week.end, cor_df$asw)
```

Expected output:

```
week.end cor_df.asw
1 2020-08-22          0
2 2020-08-29          1
3 2020-09-05          2
4 2020-10-03          3
5 2020-10-17          2
6 2020-10-24          3
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get you there starting with the `EndStates` data frame.  I'm not sure whether it will be much faster.  Because `dplyr` does thing to the columns all at once (rather than sequentially down the column), I still needed a `while()` loop to do some of the filling in missing weeks.  Perhaps a better `dplyr` person will provide an alternative.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
cor_df2 <- EndStates %>%
  mutate(count = as.numeric(WeekEndState == "Correction")) %>% 
  select(-WeekEndState) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols="week.end", names_from="CaseNo", values_from="count") %>% 
  arrange(week.end) %>%
  mutate(across(-week.end, function(x)case_when(is.na(x) & week.end == min(week.end) ~ 0, TRUE ~ x)))

while(any(is.na(cor_df2))){
  cor_df2 <- cor_df2 %>% mutate(across(-week.end, function(x)case_when(is.na(x)~lag(x), TRUE ~ x)))
}  
cor_df2 <- cor_df2 %>%   
  mutate(asw = rowSums(.[-1])) %>% 
  select(week.end, asw)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help here! Tested it on my 5000 case df, looks good. ONto my 5.5 million one!